# Jflex Regular expression

Tags: java, regex, jflex

I am trying to write a .flex file that recognises a string literal,which is a sequence of characters surrounded by double quotes. No escape characters, but I just cant get it to identify them, This is my latest attempt.

```
\"(\\.|[^"])*\"
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use instead

```
\"(.[^\"]*)\"
```

Comment: <YYINITIAL>(\"(\\.|[^"]+)*\")        {return new Token (Token.STRING, yytext());}

Comment: YYINITIAL is the inital scanning state

Comment: Simply use `\"[^\"]*\"`?